# Formatting cells in Excel so that the face value becomes the actual value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've received data and I want to flag certain units of measurement. The cells have been formattted such that for example, upon face value it says 25 kg but when I click on it, it says 25 which is messing up my flagging of the UoM. Has anyone got any ideas of how to fix this?

Ive tried a couple of formatting types but none have worked thus far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.